lyx finding style files
I am attempting to use lyx on a Rocky 8 machine. When I load a revtex4 document I get the message that it can't find revtex4.cls or revsymb.sty. However, when I look in Tools=> Tex info, under latex classes, it lists revtex4.cls as found under latex classes, and revsymb.sty found under LaTeX styles. Can someone demystify me?

How up to date is your TeX distribution? Is the revtex4-2 class similarly missing? Can you reproduce the error compiling a tex document in the terminal?

There are RevTeX V. 4, V.4.1 and V 4.2. Maybe you have trying to compile a revtex4-1 or revtex4-2 class but t you only have revtex4.cls. Make a grep textclass foo.lyx   or lyx foo.lyx → Document → Settings ... → Document class → Unknow text class revtex* to see what is the * exactly.

Rocky 8 appears to package TL 2018 which I believe only ever had revtex4-1, can you run kpsewhich revtex4.cls in the terminal to check if it's actually on the system?
